# Не отображать элементы при компиляции проекта

Tags: java

Мне нужно сделать проект на практике. Но вот столкнулся с проблемой, когда компилируешь проект, то элементы появляются, когда изменишь размер формы или наведешь на их место мышь...
[image]

[image]

Base:

```
public class Base extends JPanel{
    int tovar[]={'5','8','0','6','8'};
    int lampX=70, lampY=50, lotokWidth=0;
    int i=0;
    static int lotokup=250;

    boolean works=false;
    public void drawDemo(boolean work, int lampX1, int lampY1, int w, int h, Graphics2D g2
        , int lotokWidth){
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        Shape shape = null;
        shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(lampX1, lampY1, 9, 10);     
        g2.draw(shape);
        if(work==true){
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillOval(lampX, lampY, 9, 10);
        }
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawRect(lotokWidth, lotokup, 50, 50);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Main k = new Main();
        Dimension d = getSize();
        g2.setBackground(getBackground());
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            switch(i){
            case 0 : lampX=70; lampY=50; lotokWidth=70; break;
            case 1 : lampX=150; lampY=50; lotokWidth=150; break;
            case 2 : lampX=230; lampY=50; lotokWidth=230; break;
            case 3 : lampX=310; lampY=50; lotokWidth=310; break;
            case 4 : lampX=390; lampY=50; lotokWidth=390; break;
            default : lampX=0; lampY=0;
            }
            if(tovar[i]>'0'){
                works = false;
            }else{
                works = true;
            }
            drawDemo(works, lampX, lampY,d.width, d.height, g2, lotokWidth);
        }
    }    
}
```

Elements:

```
public class Elements extends Base{
    int lotokX=700, lotokY=50;
    boolean works;
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Товар 1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Товар 2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("Товар 3");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("Товар 4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("Товар 5");   
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame form = new JFrame("Торговый автомат");
        form.setLayout(null);
        form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        form.setSize(600, 400);
        form.setVisible(true);
        Elements element = new Elements();
        Base lamps = new Base();
        lamps.setBounds(5, 5, 400, 300);
        form.getContentPane().add(lamps);
        element.setBounds(5, 5, 600, 400);
        form.getContentPane().add(element);

        //Position
        element.button1.setBounds(40, 20, 80, 30);
        element.button2.setBounds(120, 20, 80, 30);
        element.button3.setBounds(200, 20, 80, 30);
        element.button4.setBounds(280, 20, 80, 30);
        element.button5.setBounds(360, 20, 80, 30);
        // Added
        form.getContentPane().add(element.button1);
        form.getContentPane().add(element.button2);
        form.getContentPane().add(element.button3);
        form.getContentPane().add(element.button4);
        form.getContentPane().add(element.button5);

        form.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Такое бывает из-за багов в видео-драйверах. Ява использует всякое аппаратное ускорение, а с ним бывают косяки. Попробуйте выключить использование DirectX.

Comment: Попробую но что-то мне подсказывает что дело не в этом

Comment: Нужно смотреть в код, мало ли как там оно создается.
Видеоускорение тут точно не причем. Ну разве только если очень криво установлены драйвера.

Comment: да такое уже 4-х компах

Comment: Хорошо бы код увидеть

Comment: пытался, но тут че-то не позволяет много символов в комент писать, вобщем щас залью исходник http://narod.ru/disk/32898756001/workspase.rar.html

Comment: Посмотрел код. Ужаснулся. в процедуре отрисовки код вида `Main k = new Main();` - это нечто. 
Разберитесь с тем, как позиционируются элементы в окне, нужно ли их накладывать друг на дружку и потестируйте каждый по  отдельности.

Comment: да, код не идеален я новичек просто в этом деле, но все же ... жду помочи в решении проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте в конце вашего переопределенного метода paint добавить вызов базового (как вариант в начале)

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

// делаем что-то полезное для нас
...

// позволяем базовому классу сделать что-то полезное
super.paint(g);
}
```

Comment: ответ я нашел, нужно просто перерисовать елемент, а именно на пример setVisible(false); а потом true

Answer (score 0):

Переопределяйте метод `paintComponent` вместо метода `paint`. Так как последний отвечает за отображение не только самой панели, но и её содержимого.

P.S. Не запускал. Но, на первый взгляд, должно помочь.